# How to add color to a cell with a null value using xlsx-color library

Tags: javascript, excel, colors, xlsx

I'm trying to add a background color to a cell when generating an xlsx sheet. I am using the aoa_to_sheet function using the `sheetStubs` option to generate cells for null values. Using `sheetStubs: true` I'm able to see the cell B2 when I print out all the cells - this was not the case without the `sheetStubs` option. After the sheet is generated I'm trying to add colors to individual cells for testing purposes...but only cells with a non-undefined and non-null `v` value are getting colors added to them when the file is generated.

Here's the test code I've been playing with:

```
import xlsx from 'xlsx-color';

const testWorksheetData = [
  ['Header 1', 'Header 2', 'Header 3'],
  ['Value 1', null, 'Value 3'],
];

const testWorksheet = xlsx.utils.aoa_to_sheet(testWorksheetData, { sheetStubs: true });

// Set color to red for cell B2 which has a null value
const nullCellAddress = 'B2';
const nullCell = testWorksheet[nullCellAddress];
nullCell.s = { fill: { fgColor: { rgb: 'FF0000' } } };

// set color to teal for cell B1 which has a string value
const colorCellAddress = 'B1';
const colorCell = testWorksheet[colorCellAddress];
colorCell.s = { fill: { fgColor: { rgb: '00FFFF' } } };

// write the worksheet to a workbook and then to a file
const wb = xlsx.utils.book_new();
xlsx.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, testWorksheet, `Test`);
xlsx.writeFile(wb, 'test.xlsx');
```

The sheet object looks like this:

```
{
  "A1": { "v": "Header 1", "t": "s" },
  "B1": {
    "v": "Header 2",
    "t": "s",
    "s": {
      "fill": {
        "fgColor": {
          "rgb": "FF0000"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "C1": { "v": "Header 3", "t": "s" },
  "A2": { "v": "Value 1", "t": "s" },
  "B2": {
    "v": null,
    "t": "z",
    "s": {
      "fill": {
        "fgColor": {
          "rgb": "FFFF00"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "C2": { "v": "Value 3", "t": "s" },
  "!ref": "A1:C2"
}
```

It outputs a file that looks like this:
[Screenshot of excel output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWd96.png)